# How to calculate shortest distance between user current location and multiple geo coordinate

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am working on system that provides product pick up facility from stores around him,
I have user's current location, 
I also have Geo-coordinates of all 500+ stores that are available for product pick up.

1) I want to restrict the stores to be shown on map that lies above 5 KM of radius from the user current location.

2) Calculate the travel distance (route) via road for each and every store which are present within 5 KM radius from user current location.

I am unable to figure out which Google map apis should be implemented that can solve this 2 problems as I need to give support on iPhone, Android and Website.

Looking for some help/suggestion/guidance. Thanks

Comment: this needs to be done on client side, where once you have downloaded list of geocode loop through of them to calculate the distance from the user current location

Comment: Yes, but i am confused with what api to be used to get the desired result. I just need the google api name that could help me fix this.

Comment: iOS SDK are a class called CLLoation that has methods to get distance, i assume android has something along the lines aswell...

Answer (score 0):

> 1) I want to restrict the stores to be shown on map that lies above 5
>   KM of radius from the user current location.

You can use the [Haversine formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) to calculate the distance. You can read [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3?csw=1) how to do it with PHP and MySQL.

On Android the [Location](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html) class has a method `distanceTo` to calculate a distance between two locations.

> 2) Calculate the travel distance (route) via road for each and every
>   store which are present within 5 KM radius from user current location.

You can use the [Google Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/) to find a route and calculate the distance.